# jQuery source code uses Require.js, but the final file doesn't?

Tags: jquery, requirejs, amd

Uncompressed jQuery file: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js
jQuery Source code: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js

What are they doing to make it seem like the final output is not using Require.js under the hood? Require.js examples tells you to insert the entire library into your code to make it work standalone as a single file.

Almond.js, a smaller version of Require.js also tell you to insert itself into your code to have a standalone javascript file.

When minified, I don't care for extra bloat, it's only a few extra killobytes (for almond.js), but unminified is barely readable. I have to scroll all the way down, past almond.js code to see my application logic.

#### Question

*How can I make my code to be similar to jQuery, in which the final output does not look like a Frankenweenie?*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Short answer:

You have to create your own custom build procedure.

#### Long answer

jQuery's build procedure works only because jQuery defines its modules according to a pattern that allows a `convert` function to transform the source into a distributed file that does not use `define`. If anyone wants to replicate what jQuery does, there's no shortcut: 1) the modules have to be designed according to a pattern which will allow stripping out the `define` calls, and 2) you have to have a custom conversion function. That's what jQuery does. The entire logic that combines the jQuery modules into one file is in [build/tasks/build.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/build/tasks/build.js).

This file defines a custom configuration that it passes to `r.js`. The important option are:

- `out` which is set to `"dist/jquery.js"`. This is the single
  file produced by the optimization.
- `wrap.startFile` which is set to `"src/intro.js"`. This file
  will be prepended to `dist/jquery.js`.
- `wrap.endFile` which is set to `"src/outro.js"`. This file will
  be appended to `dist/jquery.js`.
- `onBuildWrite` which is set to `convert`. This is a [custom function](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/b24a3d5368ab1243ac43c773b318519da2f0ae7b/build/tasks/build.js#L44).

The convert function is called every time `r.js` wants to output a module into the final output file. The output of that function is what `r.js` writes to the final file. It does the following:

- If a module is from the `var/` directory, the module will be
  transformed as follows. Let's take the case of
  [src/var/toString.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/var/toString.js):

  ```
  define([
      "./class2type"
      ], function( class2type ) {
      return class2type.toString;
  });
  ```

  It will become:

  ```
  var toString = class2type.toString;
  ```
- Otherwise, the `define(...)` call is replace with the contents of the callback passed to `define`, the final `return` statement is stripped and any assignments to `exports` are stripped.

I've omitted details that do not specifically pertain to your question.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a tool called AMDClean by gfranko https://www.npmjs.org/package/amdclean
It's much simpler than what jQuery is doing and you can set it up quickly.

All you need to do is to create a very abstract module (the one that you want to expose to global scope) and include all your sub modules in it.

Another alternative that I've recently been using is [browserify](http://browserify.org/). You can export/import your modules the NodeJS way and use them in any browser. You need to compile them before using it. It also has [gulp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-browserify) and [grunt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-browserify) plugins for setting up a workflow. For better explanations read the documentations on [browserify.org](http://browserify.org).